# Pyspark Py4JJavaError on .getOrCreate() creating Spark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, session, pyspark

I am trying to create a spark session, but get an error. My code:

```
spark = (SparkSession
.builder
.config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord)
.config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord)
.getOrCreate())
```

Beforehand I have imported SparkSession (`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row`) and installed pyspark, findspark, and some more packages. My code gives the following error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------

------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 5
      1 spark = (SparkSession
      2     .builder
      3     .config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord)
      4     .config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord)
----> 5     .getOrCreate())

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:477, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    475     sparkConf.set(key, value)
    476 # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 477 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    478 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    479 # by all sessions.
    480 session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:512, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    510 with SparkContext._lock:
    511     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 512         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    513     assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    514     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:200, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls, memory_profiler_cls)
...
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:515)
    ... 23 more
```

I have tried fixing it using

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

However, even though this does not give any errors, it does not fix te problem.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: Why put everything inside a bracket? spark = `(`SparkSession ... .getOrCreate()`)`

Comment: I am using the sparksession for PyDeequ, the code was provided like this the quickstart code, deleting the brackets/changing the indentation does not fix the problem.